# Need help getting a custom layout to work with my Android AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have successfully created a working AlertDialog for my Android application:

```
public class MyClass extends DialogFragment{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayList selectedItems = new ArrayList();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_toppings)
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.my_array, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    selectedItems.add(which);
                } else if (selectedItems.contains(which)) {
                    selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // do stuff here ...
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // do stuff here ...
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

This MultiChoiceItems list is backed by an array in `/res/values/array.xml`

```
<resources>
    <array name="my_array">
        <item>item 01</item>
        <item>item 02</item>
        <item>item 03</item>
        <item>item 04</item>
        <item>item 05</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

From my Activity, I call the AlertDialog this way:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "My Dialog");
```

What I want to do now is use a custom layout with the AlertDialog so that I can do things like alternate-row shading, custom buttons, and add an EditText so I can have an "other" option with the ability to fill in the "other".

After doing some googling, it looks like I need to create a new layout, and set the view of the AlertDialog to this layout. So, I created a layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="other"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I added this to my DialogFragment class:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_new_layout, null);
```

then

```
builder.setView(view);
```

As you can guess, this did not work. The new CheckBox and EditText was inserted after my other checkboxes that were populated from my array, but it looks terrible, and I don't appear to have any control over the appearance of the checkboxes created from the array.

Like I said, I would like the ability to add this new CheckBox/EditText combination, as well as have the ability to customize the look of the entire AlertDialog.

I really want to use the array from `/res/values/array.xml` so that I do not have to hard code a new option if I want to add new items to the list.

Is what I am wanting to do possible? If so, some advice would be great.

Thanks

This is what I would like my AlertDialog to look/act like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured this out on my own. Here is my resolution:

**New Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right">
</LinearLayout>
```

**New Class:**

```
public class MyClass extends DialogFragment{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] theOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_toppings)

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

        for(String option : theOptions){
            CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(getContext());
            checkbox.setText(option);
            view.addView(checkbox);
        }

        LinearLayout otherLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        otherLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        otherLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        otherLinearLayout.setId(R.id.otherLinearLayout);

        CheckBox otherCheckBox = new CheckBox(getContext());
        otherCheckBox.setText("other");
        otherCheckBox.setId(R.id.otherCheckBox);

        EditText otherEditText = new EditText(getContext());
        otherEditText.setId(R.id.otherEditText);

        otherLinearLayout.addView(otherCheckBox);
        otherLinearLayout.addView(otherEditText);

        view.addView(otherLinearLayout);

        builder.setView(view);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // do stuff here ...
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // do stuff here ...
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why are you adding the views programatically and not just with the xml? You are not doing anything special.

Comment: Because I would like to create the views from a potentially changing list of inputs (i.e., I might have 5 today, but 15 next year). This way, I don't have to go back and hard-code in another 10 checkboxes for the change; I just need to update the array in `/res/values/array.xml` and everything else gets updated automagically.

Comment: Makes sense, think I missed the for loop last time reading it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, get the array using

```
String[] myarray =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);
```

and the create new checkbox objects using each array item and set it to the inflated view

```
LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(context); layout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and loop through your array list

```
layout2.addView(new Checkbox(context));
```

and finally add the parent linear layout to the inflated view `inflatedView.addView(layout2);`

Comment: I was following along until you got to "set it to the inflated view". I'm still fairly new to Android development, and am not 100% sure how to set code-generated view items to an inflated xml layout.

Comment: try something like this

Comment: LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(context);

layout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

and loop through your array list 
layout2.addView(new Checkbox(context));

and finally add the parent linar layout to the inflated view
inflatedView.addView(layout2);

you can always call the addView methods to add views dynamically into a layout

Comment: I'm with you until `inflatedView.addView(layout2);`. My _inflatedView_, which is `View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_new_layout, null);` from my original post, does not have "addView()" available to it.

Comment: Since you are using a custom linear layout cast the view to a linear layout so that you get the add view option

Comment: I tried `View view = (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_new_layout, null);`, but the addView() method is still not available.

Comment: LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_new_layout, null);

Comment: That didn't work either. It just inflated the XML layout, and didn't add the Java-generated CheckBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

> Create Custom Dialog Fragment and add all items and checkboxes inside
>   the new layout defined by programmatically i.e dynamically.Write the
>   code for checkItemSelectedListener in your code.